# Eclipse Java - Android app using serial do not work

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to use an app in Eclipse (v3.8), but it don't work.
The API is 19, and the app is [Serial_Port_1.1.apk](https://code.google.com/p/android-serialport-api/downloads/detail?name=SerialPort_1.1.apk)

My method: (I'm new with eclipse)

- Extract the apk with apktool
- Import the folder with Eclipse
- Run as: Android application

I got theses errors:

```
threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3ac2ba8)
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: android_serialport_api.sample, PID: 1508
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application android_serialport_api.sample.Application: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android_serialport_api.sample.Application" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/android_serialport_api.sample-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/android_serialport_api.sample-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:516)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4317)
```

I'm trying to connect an Arduino to Eclipse, and the app works fine on a real system (ARM Orange Pi)

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the LogCat, there is a `ClassNotFoundException` when you try to run it after decompile. As I understood, the original app works but after decompile + recompile it won't work again, throwing a CNF. This means that your decompile process didn't work properly. I suggest you trying the [Android APK Decompiler](http://www.decompileandroid.com/), which is a free online tool.
Note: I haven't tested it yet, but it should work.

Comment: with this source it's worth.. Android don't want to start at all

Comment: so I managed to get the source in this page: https://code.google.com/p/android-serialport-api/source/checkout
The app can be launched.